# WebsocketPP client in DLL

Tags: c++, dll, websocket, boost-asio

How to create websocket client in DLL?
https://github.com/zaphoyd/websocketpp/blob/master/examples/echo_client/echo_client.cpp

ws.h

```cpp
#pragma once
typedef websocketpp::client<websocketpp::config::asio_client> client;

using websocketpp::lib::placeholders::_1;
using websocketpp::lib::placeholders::_2;
using websocketpp::lib::bind;

// pull out the type of messages sent by our config
typedef websocketpp::config::asio_client::message_type::ptr message_ptr;

class ws_point :public boost::noncopyable
{
public:
    typedef boost::system::error_code error_code;
    typedef ws_point type;
    typedef std::chrono::duration<int, std::micro> dur_type;
    websocketpp::connection_hdl ghdl;
    bool connected;
    bool inited;
    boost::thread run_thread;
    std::thread test;

    ws_point();
    ~ws_point();
    void init();
    void connect(std::string& uri);
    void disconnect();
    void send(websocketpp::connection_hdl hdl, const char* str);
    void close(websocketpp::connection_hdl hdl, websocketpp::close::status::value code);
    void on_open(websocketpp::connection_hdl hdl);
    void on_message(websocketpp::connection_hdl hdl, message_ptr msg);
    void on_close(websocketpp::connection_hdl hdl);
    void on_fail(websocketpp::connection_hdl hdl);
private:
    client m_endpoint;
    websocketpp::lib::shared_ptr<websocketpp::lib::thread> m_thread;
};

extern std::shared_ptr<ws_point> WebSocket;
```

Problem code - disconnect.
Disconnect called in destructor DLL (called 1 times).
I dont know, maybe not use this class, maybe use Echo Client, but i dont have example echo client for DLL.
ws.cpp

```cpp
#include "main.h"
std::string wsuri = "ws://127.0.0.1:6001/ws";
std::shared_ptr<ws_point> WebSocket = nullptr;
ws_point::ws_point()
{
    SF->Log("Constructor");
    if (!inited)
    {
        m_endpoint.clear_access_channels(websocketpp::log::alevel::all);
        m_endpoint.clear_error_channels(websocketpp::log::elevel::all);
        m_endpoint.init_asio();
        m_endpoint.start_perpetual();
        m_thread = websocketpp::lib::make_shared<websocketpp::lib::thread>(&client::run, &m_endpoint);
        inited = true;
    }
}

ws_point::~ws_point()
{
    SF->Log("Destructor");
    if (!inited)
        return;
}

void ws_point::init()
{
    SF->Log("Init");
}
void ws_point::disconnect()
{
    SF->Log("Disconnect");
    if (!inited)
        return;
    m_endpoint.stop_perpetual();
    websocketpp::lib::error_code ec;
    if (connected)
        m_endpoint.close(ghdl, websocketpp::close::status::going_away, "", ec);
    /*if (ec) {
        return;
    }*/
    m_endpoint.stop();
    if (m_thread->joinable())
    {
        SF->Log("Join");
        // message sended and freezes main app.
        // if call unload 3 times > app close
        m_thread->join();
    }
    else
        SF->Log("No joinable");
    connected = false;
}

void ws_point::connect(std::string& uri) {
    SF->Log("Connect");
    if (inited)
    {
        websocketpp::lib::error_code ec;
        client::connection_ptr con = m_endpoint.get_connection(uri, ec);
        if (ec) {
            SF->Log(ec.message());
            return;
        }
        ghdl = con->get_handle();
        con->set_message_handler(bind(&type::on_message, this, ::_1, ::_2));
        con->set_open_handler(bind(&type::on_open, this, ::_1));
        con->set_close_handler(bind(&type::on_close, this, ::_1));
        con->set_fail_handler(bind(&type::on_fail, this, ::_1));
        m_endpoint.connect(con);
        SF->Log("Connected");
    }
}
```

main.cpp > initialize

```cpp
WebSocket = std::make_shared<ws_point>();
WebSocket->init();
WebSocket->connect(wsuri);
```

Comment: Please be more specific. You need to know how to create a DLL or how to create a websocket client?

Comment: i need create websocket client in my DLL.

Comment: What is exactly the issue you are experience? Is your program throwing any exception? Is it crashing? Is it running with some unexpected results?

Comment: if my lib unloading - main app freezes

Comment: What is it exactly expected to do? Then debug your program, check the exact line where it freezes, check the exact location where it freezes. And add all that details to your question, as well as answers to what is the program supposed to do.

Comment: @armagedescu 
My library is loaded into the main program (game) and collects data from it by sending and receiving information via a websocket connection (namely websocket, others are not suitable).
When I try to unload my library, the main application freezes, while I can unload the plugin exactly three times, the third time the game just closes. The problem occurs when you call join () on the websocket stream.

Comment: I created a class (from the websocketpp example) that is created via std :: shared_ptr. Inside the class there is another shared_ptr <websocketpp :: lib :: thread>. It is this thread that cannot end (as I believe).

Comment: Please edit your question and add all details to question. Also samples of code that you believe are problematic. Also why you need a library to be loaded and unloaded many times? That's not a thing that a library is supposed to be.

Comment: @armagedescu see

Comment: That's much better. So your application freezes on join? Maybe the problem is in the client class? If it freezes on join it probably means the thread does not exit. Then what is it doing? Maybe it is looping somewhere and skipping the exit part? Or maybe it waits for some synchronisation object to be released? If you use a debugger you should be able to debug your thread and see exactly where it got stuck.